# Não consigo fazer funcionar o setTimeout funcionar

Tags: javascript

**No JavaScript toda vez que insiro o setTimeout chamando a função anterior e colocando os milisegundo não funciona. Meu objetivo é automatizar a passagem de quadros, mas quero fazer com JS puro. Será que vou ter que usar o laço FOR?**

```
<html>

        <head>
            <title>Slide</title>

            <style type="text/css">

            body {

                margin: 0px;

            }

            .box-main {

                height: 500px;
                width: 900px;
                border: 5px solid gray;
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                overflow: hidden;


            }

            .box-images {

                position: absolute;
                left: 0px;
                height: 500px;
                width: 2700px;
                transition: 1s all linear;

            }

            .box-img1, .box-img2, .box-img3 {

                height: 500px;
                width: 900px;
                float: right;


            }

            .box-pointer {

                height: 500px;
                width: 900px;
                position: absolute;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: flex-end;
                z-index: 10;

            }

            .box-pointer-int {

                margin-bottom: 20px;

            }

            .pointer1, .pointer2, .pointer3 {

                height: 16px;
                width: 16px;
                border-radius: 8px;
                background-color: gray;
                float: left;
                margin-right: 5px;
                margin-left: 5px;
                opacity: 0.5;

            }

            </style>

        </head>

        <body>

            <div class = "box-main">

                <div class = "box-images">

                    <div class = "box-img1" style = "background-color: red;"></div>
                    <div class = "box-img2" style = "background-color: blue;"></div>
                    <div class = "box-img3" style = "background-color: yellow;"></div>

                </div>

                <div class = "box-pointer">

                    <div class = "box-pointer-int">

                        <div class = "pointer3" onclick = "passar3()"></div>
                        <div class = "pointer2" onclick = "passar2()"></div>
                        <div class = "pointer1" onclick = "passar1()"></div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

            <script type="text/javascript">

                var intervalo = 3000;

                function passar3() {

                    document.getElementsByClassName("box-images")[0].style.left = "0px";

                }

                function passar2() {

                    document.getElementsByClassName("box-images")[0].style.left = "-900px";

                }

                function passar1() {

                    document.getElementsByClassName("box-images")[0].style.left = "-1800px";

                }

            </script>

        </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando o setInterval e o document.addEventListener com o parâmetro "DOMContentLoaded" consegui que iniciasse automaticamente. Agora foi preciso fazer outras alterações para que o clique funcionasse junto com o giro automático. Problema que o código ficou bastante bagunçado. Adicionei alguns comentários para ficar mais claro.

```
    <head>
        <title>Slide</title>

        <style type="text/css">

        body {

            margin: 0px;

        }

        .box-main {

            height: 500px;
            width: 900px;
            border: 5px solid gray;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            overflow: hidden;


        }

        .box-images {

            position: absolute;
            left: 0px;
            height: 500px;
            width: 2700px;
            transition: 1s all linear;

        }

        .box-img1, .box-img2, .box-img3 {

            height: 500px;
            width: 900px;
            float: right;


        }

        .box-pointer {

            height: 500px;
            width: 900px;
            position: absolute;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: flex-end;
            z-index: 10;

        }

        .box-pointer-int {

            margin-bottom: 20px;

        }

        .pointer1, .pointer2, .pointer3 {

            height: 16px;
            width: 16px;
            border-radius: 8px;
            background-color: gray;
            float: left;
            margin-right: 5px;
            margin-left: 5px;
            opacity: 0.5;

        }

        </style>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div class = "box-main">

            <div class = "box-images">

                <div class = "box-img1" style = "background-color: red;"></div>
                <div class = "box-img2" style = "background-color: blue;"></div>
                <div class = "box-img3" style = "background-color: yellow;"></div>

            </div>

            <div class = "box-pointer">

                <div class = "box-pointer-int">

                    <div class = "pointer3" onclick = "atualiza_img_atual('0')"></div>
                    <div class = "pointer2" onclick = "atualiza_img_atual('1')"></div>
                    <div class = "pointer1" onclick = "atualiza_img_atual('2')"></div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            var img_atual = 1;
            var intervalo;

            function passar() {
                //calcula a posição inicial da imagem atual
                tamanho = img_atual * (-900);
                //posiciona na imagem atual
                document.getElementsByClassName("box-images")[0].style.left = tamanho + "px";
                //atualiza o numero da imagem atual, se for a última retorna para zero
                if(img_atual == 2) {
                    img_atual = 0;
                } else {
                    img_atual++;    
                }

            }
            //atualiza qual imagem será exibida
            function atualiza_img_atual(img) {
                img_atual = img;
                //interrompe o carrossel
                clearInterval(intervalo);
                //executa uma vez imediatamente
                passar();
                //inicia o carrosel novamente
                intervalo = setInterval(passar, 3000, img_atual); 
            }
            //Inicia o carrossel no load do conteúdo da página
            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
              intervalo = setInterval(passar, 3000, img_atual);
            });


        </script>

    </body>
```

Comment: Só teve a questão de atualização quando se é clicado nas bolinhas... mas isso eu sei fazer e só adicionei ao script. Quero agradecer, mas a política daqui diz para nós usuários não fazermos isso por esses meios.

Answer (score 0):

Basta você adicionar o `setTimeout` dentro das suas funções, por exemplo:

dentro da sua função `passar3` você adiciona o `setTimeout` chamando sua função `passar2`, que por sua vez teria tambem um `setTimeout` chamando a sua função `passar1`, no geral seu código ficaria dessa forma:

```
var intervalo = 3000;

    passar3();

    function passar3() {

        document.getElementsByClassName("box-images")[0].style.left = "0px";

        setTimeout(() => {
            passar2()
        }, intervalo);
    };

    function passar2() {

        document.getElementsByClassName("box-images")[0].style.left = "-900px";

        setTimeout(() => {
            passar1()
        }, intervalo);
    }

    function passar1() {

        document.getElementsByClassName("box-images")[0].style.left = "-1800px";

        setTimeout(() => {
            passar3()
        }, intervalo);

    }
```